# Should I say "These are ...." when I answer a video call with company?

Tags: telephone

We usually answer a phone saying "This is ... " to introduce who is answering.

But if I have company and want to introduce me and my company, can I say "These are ..." instead of "This is ..." ?

Or is it OK to say "This is me and my company" ?

Comment: In a business setting, I would say "Hello, John Smith here, and with me I have" and give the others' names.

Comment: Maybe you are asking if you are right to introduce yourself and two others as follows: "Hello, this is Pat, Leslie, and Kim here." That is quite normal and means this is Pat, this is Leslie... Introduce yourself last if practical. If you are drawn to the word 'these,' you can use this form: "This is Kim and _these_ are my colleagues Pat and Leslie."

Comment: This is Dilbert at Acme Engineering.

Answer (score 1):

"This is..." is traditionally used by the moderator of such a call, followed by "With me are X, Y, and Z".  Sometimes if the moderator already knows the personnel from remote sites, they'll be introduced as well.

"Representing First Base, we have Who, Second Base, by What, and I Don't Know is joining from Third Base" (kudos to Abbott and Costello).

Comment: What embarrassing names they have! lol, Thank you a lot